# Acessing LINQ to SQL data context outside the domain project

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, nunit

I crate domain project to store dbml file and several domain classes. I create unit test project to test CRUD operation. I reference domain project to the test project.

I declare the db context in the unit test, in the test method `I try to access method db.SubmitChanges(); but It is not accessible`.

But when the unit test file stored in the domain project, the db method is accessible.

```
[TestFixture]
class CustomerRepositoryTest
{
    NorthWindDataContext db = new NorthWindDataContext();
    Customer _customer = null;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp() {
        //initialize customer
    }

    [Test]
    public void Should_able_to_get_data_when_data_is_inserted()
    {
        db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(_customer);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        Customer customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerID == _customer.CustomerID);

        Assert.AreEqual(customer.CustomerID.Trim(), _customer.CustomerID);
        Assert.AreEqual(customer.ContactName.Trim(), _customer.ContactName);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void After()
    {
        db.Customers.DeleteOnSubmit(_customer);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Let me know how to fix this.

**EDIT**:

```
Error   1   'AppProject.Domain.NorthWindDataContext' does not contain a definition for 'SubmitChanges' and no extension method 'SubmitChanges' accepting a first argument of type 'AppProject.Domain.NorthWindDataContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\tutorial\dotNET\LINQtoSQL\AppProject.Spec\Should_insert_customer.cs  40  16  AppProject.Spec
```

Comment: In your example please be specific about what doesn't work as expected, as that should be fine

Comment: I try to access db context method from unit test file in unit test project. but the the method is not accessible. But when the unit test stored in the domain project, the db context method can be accessible.

Comment: What do you mean by "db context method". What line fails? What is the message?

Comment: db.SubmitChanges() is one of db context method

Comment: again, PLEASE GIVE THE EXACT MESSAGE; if it doesn't compile, tell us the compiler message. If it throws an exception at runtime, tell us the exception message.

Comment: odd; what is the base-type of `NorthWindDataContext` here?

Comment: the base type is: System.Data.Linq.DataContext, it's very add buddy :(

Comment: @MarcGravell let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1494/discussion-between-adisembiring-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add reference to `System.Data.Linq` assembly in your test project.
 The assembly reference is added to your main project when creating dbml file (data context). in order to use all of the LinqToSQL functionality, you need to reference `System.Data.Linq` in all of the projects where DataContext is used.

Comment: I already added using System.Data.LINQ, but my unit code still not get db context method. I also already use Project.Domain name space to the unit test.

Comment: You right buddy, after I recheck I forgot to add reference of `System.Data.Linq`, sorry for my mistake above.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

- you are missing one-or-more `using` directives, most likely to your db-context (solution: add `using Your.Namespace;`)
- in the DBML, maybe you set the db-context accessibility modifier to something other than `public` (solution: make it `public` in the DBML)

Comment: I already useing the Appproject.Domain in the unit test code. The dbml file stored in Appproject.Domain project. I didn't change the dbml code, I see in the visual studio the db context is public: `public partial class NorthWindDataContext` , but I can't accessed db.SubmitChanges() method

Comment: @adisembiring and again... *exact message* please